# Can I use the Spotify Web Playback SDK to stream to a discord bot? [ JavaScript to Python ]

Tags: javascript, python, discord, discord.py, spotify

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/

Can I use this to stream to an audio channel with a Discord bot written in Python? I already have a spotify premium as required, I am just wondering if the technical aspect between connecting these two applications is possible. It seems to me that the Web SDK provided is designed more for websites, and it's JavaScript based, whereas the project I am working on is entirely done in Python and on the Discord social media platform.